# 2 linked instances of Excel using CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook designed to generate PDFs.      It hangs (periodically) on the line in VBA to generate the PDF.     I have tried many things to fix it, and nothing seems to work.     Now, I am looking for an effective workaround.      The process involves a loop, with each pass through the loop producing a PDF.    When it hangs, there is nothing I can do except kill the process.
I need a way to let it continue, and generate as many as possible.

I thought of splitting it into two Excel workbooks, and having a Master workbook that would create (in VBA) an Excel instance each pass through the loop, and then have it load the PDF generator workbook, and assign the parameters to it.    Once the PDF was generated, the PDF generator would shut itself down.

This didn't work, because the Master gets stuck "waiting for an OLE action to complete" whenever the PDF generator gets hung.

Next, I tried to have the Master use Shell to launch the PDF generator, so that the two instances of Excel would not be linked, so problems with the PDF generator would not interfere with the master.
That required passing parameters with the Shell command, so that the PDF generator would receive arguments needs to produce the correct PDF.

I was able to get this to work if I launched the PDF generator from the command line:
EXCEL.EXE "C:\Users\u8015298\Tearsheet Generator\Tearsheet v4.0.1.xlsm"  /LP68586056 /OTC
(In this case, the Master was not open).

I thought I could use the same approach, just convert the command line to the equivalent in Shell, and put it into the Master.      This didn't work.     As far as I could understand, it seems to have something to do with two instances of Excel being open concurrently.

I have tried to script this with VbScript, but haven't been able to make that work.     (Likely I am just not proficient in VbScript or WScript, but in any case, it doesn't work for me).

My preferred solution would be the simplest - two linked instances of Excel, one created by the other.

If anyone can suggest a way to use that approach that is not vulnerable to the child instance hanging and  having that stop the parent instance, I would be very interested to hear how to do that.

I have run out of ideas how to proceed.

The line that hangs is:

```
Range("Print_Area").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,filename:=PDF_filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I have printed out the filename to the console, and that is NOT the root of the problem.    The filename is properly formed, and doesn't contain any wierd characters, and isn't excessively long.

To launch the PDF Generator, I was doing this:

```
        Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xl.WindowState = xlMaximized
        xl.Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Tearsheet v4.0.0.xlsm")
        wkbk.Names("Fund_RIC").RefersToRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = RIC
```

The 'RIC' variable determines what data the PDF generator should retrieve and put into the PDF.

Comment: We can help better if you show your code but as a first guess try turning off events etc: `DisplayAlerts = False, DisplayStatusBar = False, EnableAnimations = False, ScreenUpdating = False, EnableEvents = False, PrintCommunication = False`. If that doesn't work try disabling Add-Ons one by one.

Comment: I would suggest to better investigate **why "It hangs (periodically) on the line in VBA to generate the PDF"** and solve the problem... If one session create another one, if the created one hangs the first session will also be hanged, waiting for the second to finish. This is the way VBA works. If you insist on the way you propose, a third session will be necessary. It should  monitor the folder where the pdf files are created and close both session in case of no file has been created in a specific period of time. The code must log the created files, to know where from to restart the process.

Comment: So named master must have an `Open` event to check the log file and create the second session after the last pdf file created... It must be started using Shell. Otherwise, the third session will be also hanged together with the first two.

Comment: If you want to kick off a method without waiting for it to complete you can use `appXL.Run Now, "Slave.xlsm!Module1.LongRunning"` where appXL is your other instance.

Comment: Thanks Absinthe.      I already had screenupdating switched off, but I have added the others following your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Tim.        It isn't a problem for the Master to wait for the PDF generator, so long as the PDF generator is eventually successful, and doesn't end up hanging.       As I understand your suggestion, application.Run would allow the Master to tell the PDF Generator to run a macro, and do it asynchronously.        I wasn't familar with this approach, although I hadn't needed it, since PDF Generator has an process to detect a specific cell changing value, and that is what kicks off the process of generating the PDF.

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru.       I agree with your suggestion about trying to focus on the source of why the line to produce the PDF causes the process to hang.       i have read suggestions that this is connected to the availability of the printer settings, but my tests indicate that the process sometimes fails even when I have a network connection to the printer, and the printer is online.

Comment: Actually I wrote the wrong thing all together: what I mean to write was:  If you want to kick off a method without waiting for it to complete you can use `appXL.OnTime Now, "Slave.xlsm!Module1.LongRunning"`   `Run` will wait until the called macro is done, but using `OnTime` just sets the schedule and returns right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the root problem, which was the freezing when producing the PDF.
I found that under rare, sporadic circumstances, the data retrieval was NOT complete when the PDF generation started.      After putting in place checks to ensure the data retrievals were complete before the PDF generation was started, the problem disappeared.

I didn't find a reliable way to start one Excel instance from another and pass arguments WITHOUT the use of VBA, however I no longer need that to solve the root issue.